# Custom Controller, not working with areas

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, controller

I have a custom controller in my project because I use Structure Map as an IOC Container. When I add Datatables.mvc (library for jquery grid), and call a view from areas, the custom Controller does not work at runtime and gives me an error. When I remove the Datatables.mvc from references, the project compiles successfully and renders the view form controller as well.

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

        setDbInitializer();
        //Set current Controller factory as StructureMapControllerFactory
        ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new StructureMapControllerFactory());
        Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.GlobalHost.DependencyResolver = SmObjectFactory.Container.GetInstance<Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.IDependencyResolver>();
    }
    private static void setDbInitializer()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<OnlineAcademyDbContext, Configuration>());
        SmObjectFactory.Container.GetInstance<IUnitOfWork>().ForceDatabaseInitialize();
    }
    public class StructureMapControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
    {
        protected override IController GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
        {
            if (controllerType == null)
            {
                throw new HttpException(404, $"Resource not found : {requestContext.HttpContext.Request.Path}");
            }
            return SmObjectFactory.Container.GetInstance(controllerType) as Controller;
        }
    }
    protected void Application_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpContextLifecycle.DisposeAndClearAll();
    }
}
```

and this is the error when i called a view from areas and Datatable.mvc has been add to references:

> System.Web.HttpException: Resource not found : url of area...
>   ControllerType is null

thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

well. problem has been solved. the solution is change the computer. i think the iis or Os got confuse cause